# How to calculate Vx for a propeller driven airplane?

Tags: aircraft-performance

I know that Vx for jet engines airplane is at Vmd and that Vy is at 1.32 Vmd;
I do also know that Vy for propeller airplanes is at Vmd.
Now I cannot figure out where i can get the Vx for propellers.

Comment: Do you mean $V_{MD}$ or $V_{MC}$

Comment: Vmd (minimum control speed)

Comment: The ratio between max. range and max. endurance speeds is always 3^0.25 = 1.316...   It's the same for prop planes, jet planes, or gliders.

Comment: v$_{mD}$ is minimum drag speed, when induced and zero-lift drag are equal.